# How to get the value of a function in the query by passing it in arguments

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, jdbctemplate

```java
 StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

  query.append("SELECT * from Demography Demo")
  .append(" WHERE Demo.Roll IN ( '5', '1') AND DemoVer.Roll is null ")
  .append(" AND date(Demo.Updt) between ")
  .append("date('").append("?").append("') AND  CURRENT DATE-100 DAY");

  final Object[] args = new Object[]{getVal()};

  result = jdbcTemplate.query(query, args, new Mapper());
```

My query generated is showing "?" only instead of the value from the function

Edit 1:  Its still showing ? instead of the value. I am not sure if the code for executing the query is fine.

```java
query.append("SELECT * from Demography Demo")
  .append(" WHERE Demo.Roll IN ( '5', '1') AND DemoVer.Roll is null ")
  .append(" AND date(Demo.Updt) between ")
  .append(" timestamp(?)").append(" AND CURRENT DATE-100 DAY");

  final Object[] args = new Object[] {
        getVal() 
    } ; //its returning '2020-09-01 03:00:00'
    int[] types = new int[] { Types.CHAR  };
    List<Record> result = null;  
    result = jdbcTemplate.query(query, args, types, new Mapper());
```

Generated query -

```
SELECT * from Demography Demo WHERE Demo.Roll IN ( '5', '1') AND DemoVer.Roll is null 
   AND date(Demo.Updt) between
   timestamp(?) AND CURRENT DATE-100 DAY
```

Expected query -

```
SELECT * from Demography Demo WHERE Demo.Roll IN ( '5', '1') AND DemoVer.Roll is null 
   AND date(Demo.Updt) between
   timestamp('2020-09-01 03:00:00') AND CURRENT DATE-100 DAY
```

Error :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.19.66
```

Full StackTrace :

```
nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.19.66
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:93) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1444) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:706) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:758) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at com.optum.chy.component.DB2Service.selectData(DB2Service.java:278) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: You currently have a string literal containing a question mark (`'?'`), not a parameter placeholder (`?`) (that is **without quotes**)

Comment: I need to get the date from the timestamp here, like this -> date('2020-01-01 03:00:00')

Comment: Your current query is literally `date('?')`, that is you are passing a **string** with a question mark to `date(...)`. Use `date(?)`, or - if that doesn't work - try `cast(? as date)`, or simply use `?` and make sure the value you pass is in fact a `java.sql.Date` or a `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: Its not working @MarkRotteveel, please see the edits in the post.

Comment: What do you mean with _"It is still showing ? instead of the value"_? Where is it showing that?

Comment: The query is having the "?" appended to it , instead of the value from the function getVal()

Comment: **Where**? When you use a prepared statement, then - in most database systems - the query will always contain the parameter placeholder. The value you apply will be passed separately on execute (as in "for parameter 1, use value _x_"). The parameter value is not interpolated in the query string itself (there are some exceptions like the MySQL Connector/J with default connection settings). So the fact the query itself has a ? is correct. If you get an error, or not the expected results, that is a different problem.

Comment: I'm sorry , I'm quite new to programming, I understand your point now.. but ..How to fix it ? What can be done with the query code  or execution code ?

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem? The query should contain a parameter placeholder, that is how it works. If something isn't working, then clearly demonstrate what isn't working (and **how** it isn't working, eg what do you expect and what is the actual result, or the error you get).

Comment: updated the question

Comment: You still don't seem to grasp that it is correct that the query has a `?` in it: that is the query that is sent to the server to be prepared (the prepared/compile statement then gets an id, say id=5), on execute the driver tells the server "execute prepared statement with id = 5 with parameter 1 value '2020-09-01 03:00:00'). The parameter placeholder in the query is **never replaced**, that is how this works in most database systems. So I'm asking one more time: is there actually a problem (eg doesn't the query work, or produce the wrong result)?

Comment: The query doesn't work, presence of a '?' throws Bad SQL Grammer Exception. The query should execute and store the output in the variable "result"

Comment: Please include the full exception stacktrace in your question.

Comment: updated the question with stacktrace